# Tensorflow の C++ api のビルド方法 (Windows, mingw-w64, g++)

Tags: c++, windows, tensorflow, gcc, mingw

tensorflowには、C++ APIが用意されており、以下にリファレンスもありました。
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc

しかし、C++に**導入**する方法が書いておらず、ライブラリのバイナリも配布されていません。
私はmingw-w64のg++をコンパイラとして利用しているのですが、そちらにインストールする方法をご教示いただきたいです。

バイナリからビルドすればよいのかと思い、以下のTensorflowのビルドのドキュメントも拝見しましたが、pipパッケージをビルドしており、C++に関する情報は得られませんでした。
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows?hl=ja

下記のstackoverflowの投稿も拝見しましたが、contribディレクトリは最新のtensorflowでは削除されているためCMakeLists.txtは存在せず、現在はCMakeでのビルドはサポートされていないようでした。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41070330/is-it-possible-to-use-tensorflow-c-api-on-windows

追記
公式のドキュメントに示されている方法に用いられているbazelは、どうやらVisual C++とclangにしか対応していないようです。bazelでビルドする場合はmingwのg++を使うのは難しいかもしれません。
https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/windows.html#build-on-windows

Comment: 既読かもしれませんが、この辺の記事が関係してそうです。[Deep Learningアプリケーション開発 (3) TensorFlow with C](https://qiita.com/iwatake2222/items/d7cb2bd10a8bbb81cd8b), [TensorFlow for C のインストール](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/lang_c?hl=ja), [tensorflow/tensorflow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/lib_package/README.md)

Comment: @kunif ありがとうございます。内部で関わっている可能性はあるのですが、c_api.hはC言語のAPIであり、C++のAPIとは別ものだと思われます。

Comment: おっと、それは失礼。内容を理解していませんでしたね。

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/c/c_api.h を見ると `extern "C"` が明示されているのでそのまま C++ で使えそうです。

Comment: @774RR コメントありがとうございます。確かにC++で使うことは可能なように作られていますが、私が使いたいのはC++ APIです。c_api.hはCでかかれたC言語用のAPIですので、名前空間やオブジェクトのメモリ管理などの点から見ても、C++からはなるべく(ましてやC++ APIが用意されているのに)使うべきではないと考えています。

Comment: 要望の環境ではなくLinuxのDocker用でこんなのがあるようです。[FloopCZ/tensorflow_cc](https://github.com/FloopCZ/tensorflow_cc) TF-2.2対応らしいですね。CMakeLists.txtもあるようなので、参考になるかも。関連QA記事 [List of headers to use Tensorflow C++ API using libtensorflow_cc.so](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42898577/9014308)

Comment: Win32API は名前空間に対応してないとかクラス化されてないとかの理由で C++ から使うべきでないみたいな書き方ですね。あなたの好きなようにクラス化するのはどうでしょうか。

Comment: @kunif ありがとうございます。見てみます。

Comment: 手順に従ってVisual C++を使用してビルドを行い、作成されたDLLをMinGWで使用するのではだめなのでしょうか？

Comment: @sayuri コメントありがとうございます。

Comment: @sayuri まちがえて途中で送信してしまいました、すみません。私も初めそう考えていたのですが、以下のURLにあるteratailの解答を見ると、VC++で生成されたdllはオーバーロードされた関数などへの識別子の付け方がMinGWと違うため、互換性がないようなのですよね。。だめもとで試すか迷いましたが、望みが薄そうなので今のところは試していません。https://teratail.com/questions/124670#reply-190035